# Button click redirect if code is right

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I am trying to set it up so that there are two buttons. A 'checkout' button and a 'checkout with code' button. If you hit the 'checkout' button, you're redirected to a page. I have that done with no problems at all.

For the 'checkout with code' button, if the code is right, you'll be redirected to a different page. If the code is wrong, an alert will come up and say "Invalid Code". I don't know how to make the button redirect you to the second page if you get the code right.

Here's my coding:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    //this is the code that is used to checkout, when you press the checkout with code button.
    var code = 123456
    //if code is right, redirect to page2
    function checkOut2 () {
        if (code = 123456) {window.location.pathname = "nintendo.com"} else {
            alert("Invalid Code");
        }
    }
</script>
<html>
    <body>
        <button type="button" onclick="location.href = 'www.yoursite1.com'" id="checkOut">Checkout</button>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button type="button" id="checkOut2">Checkout With Code</button>
        <br>
        Code:
        <input type="text" name="code">
        <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

So, when you press the Checkout With Code button and have a valid code in the Code textbox, you'd be redirected to nintendo.com. But I have no idea how to make this work properly..

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator, _not_ the comparison operator.

Comment: just use ===  instead

Comment: Javascript is client-side, I'd advise against checking the code on the client side because it's more-or-less visible in your sourcecode. (Mind you, you could check the md5 or something like that, but it's still not a good idea.)

Comment: To get valid HTML, the `button` [must be inside a `form` or specify its form with a `form` attributes anyway](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button), so why not use the `action` attribute on the form to go where you want to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really read some Javascript tutorials, this is a simple thing to do.

```
function checkOut2() {

    var code = document.getElementById("code").value;
    if(code == "123456"){
       window.location = "nintendo.com"
    } else {
       alert("Invalid Code");
    }

}

<input type="text" id="code">
<button type="button" id="checkOut2" onclick="checkOut2();">Checkout With Code</button>
```

Comment: Change id to name. <input name="code">

Comment: You changed an input with name to an input with id. So it is ok now.

Answer (score 1):

First, fix the operator you use to compare from `=` to `==`.

```
function checkOut2 () {
        if (code == 123456) {window.location.pathname = "nintendo.com"} else {
            alert("Invalid Code");
        }
    }
```

Then try attaching your function as an event listener:

```
var button = document.getElementById('checkOut2');
button.addEventListener("click", checkOut2);
```

Also, to retrieve the code from the input, first add an id attribute:

```
<input type="text" id="code"/>
```

Then, retrieve it in javascript like:

```
var code = document.getElementById('code').value;
```